# Can I use the normal form of a value to avoid incomplete pattern matches in Agda?

Tags: agda

In the following Agda program, I get a warning about a missing case in the definition of `one`, despite the fact that `myList` only fits the `cons` case.

```agda
open import Data.Nat

data List (A : Set) : Set where
  nil : List A
  cons : A → List A → List A

myList : List ℕ
myList = cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil))

one : ℕ
one with myList 
... | (cons x xs) = x
```

```
Incomplete pattern matching for .test.with-16. Missing
cases:
  one | nil
```

I know that this sounds a bit convoluted but is there a way to define `one` in terms of `myList`, without running into "incomplete pattern matching" errors?

This example is a simplification of my original problem, which is from a homework assignment and which uses slightly more complicated types. In that case, `"myList"` is a large value computed by a clever function from a small input. If I compute the normal form of `"myList"` using Emacs' Agda Mode (C-c C-n), I can grab the value of `"one"` from that and paste it into my program. However, this value takes dozens of lines when printed out so I was wandering if there is a way to directly define `"one"` in terms of `"myList"`, without running into the incomplete pattern matching error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reflect a value at the type level and then pattern match on it. Looks like this:

```
open import Data.Nat

data List (A : Set) : Set where
  nil : List A
  cons : A → List A → List A

myList : List ℕ
myList = cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil))

data Sing {α} {A : Set α} : A -> Set where
  sing : ∀ x -> Sing x

one : ℕ
one with sing myList
... | sing (cons x (cons _ (cons _ nil))) = x
```

Comment: This version worked great on my original problem (lambda calculus evaluator)! Would you have any idea why it was more efficient than the "refl" solution that Saizan suggested?

Comment: @hugomg, sorry, don't know why the `refl` solution is not efficient. I suggest to try asking on the Agda mailing list. This might turn out to be a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `with e` then `e` gets abstracted (think lambda abstraction) from the goal and context, and you are asked to continue as if you had a variable there instead of `e` itself. So the following pattern matching doesn't take into account the value of `myList` at all (which is fairly counter-intutive, but with is just syntactic sugar for creating an auxiliary definition with one extra argument).

You can however write the following:

```
open import Agda.Builtin.List
open import Agda.Builtin.Nat renaming (Nat to ℕ)
open import Agda.Builtin.Equality

myList : List ℕ
myList = 1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ []

head : {n : ℕ} {ns : List ℕ} (xs : List ℕ) → n ∷ ns ≡ xs → ℕ
head (x ∷ xs) refl = x

one : ℕ
one = head myList refl
```

You can also look at the `inspect` pattern in the standard library for a more general solution to this problem.

Comment: This seems to do the trick! But are you aware if there is a performance difference between computing `x` this way or using the normal form (C-c C-n in Emacs)? With my larger example, the normal form can be computed very quickly but this "inspection" version consumes gygabytes of RAM and quickly starts swapping.

Comment: there can be differences, because ```myList``` now is looked at during typechecking to verify it's a ```_∷_``` and extract the two parts, when typechecking the definition of ```one```